# How do I send emails from a .php file?

Tags: 7, emails

I have developed a separate functionality using PHP in a sub folder of my Drupal site (e.g. mysite.com/myfolder/myfunc.php).

Now I want to send emails using Drupal functions. Since this is not a custom module I can't use `hook_mail()`.

How do I send an email through Drupal?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
$to = 'ABCD@example.com'; 
$subject = 'Email in PHP'; 
$message = 'This is a test email message';
$headers = 'From: ABCD@example.com' . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" . 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion(); 
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers, 'ABCD@example.com');
```

Comment: I wanted in drupal way, but in Core PHP. I did that i will post the answer after modification.